# Getting dropbox login to work with Universal Window Platform app

Tags: window, dropbox, platform, universal, hosted-app

I was trying to getting drop box login to work through my Universal Window Platform App. I have followed the steps through the following guide :  https://microsoftedge.github.io/WebAppsDocs/en-US/win10/CreateHWA.htm , where it turns my website into a Windows Store app but I can't seem to get dropbox login working. When I try click on the icon which allows users to login, it crashes the app. On the website it works perfectly.

I have tried adding https://www.dropbox.com to the URI but it didn't work.  I checked through the console and got the following problem:

```
 Dropbox:APPHOST9624: The app can’t use script to load [website url] url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app.
```

I never encountered this problem through the website.

I also encountered another error which I don't recognise the source of which was:

```
APPHOST9603: Can’t load the ActiveX plug-in that has the class ID '[Class id here]'. Apps can't load ActiveX controls.
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203912783-How-do-I-get-dropbox-login-working-through-a-Universal-Window-Platform-App- ]